# Using `%in%` with `sparseMatrix` in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Is there a command that performs the same task as `%in%` for `sparseMatrix` in R?

I have been using `which(A %in% B)` for matrices/vectors to get the indices that I need. Although the function `Matrix::which` works for `sparseMatrix`, the following error is returned when `A` and/or `B` is a `sparseMatrix`.

```r
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can access the non-zero values of a sparse matrix with `your_matrix@x`, which is a numeric vector. You could then run `%in%` on those.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this skips the indices for the zeros. Is there a way to take the zeros into account too? Thanks!

Comment: You could do an elementwise or with zero: `(vec %in% spmat@x) | (vec == 0)`

Comment: Thanks, but is this only checking whether zero exists in `spmat@x`, rather than returning the location of `vec` in `spmat@x`?

Comment: That's what `%in%` is supposed to do. If you want the location you should be using `match`, but I doubt it is implemented for sparse matrices in `Matrix`. If you want to do something like `sparseA %in% sparseB` including zeros, the result would be a dense matrix. Guess if you really need it you could redo the method yourself outputting an `lgCMatrix`, but it won't be as easy.